# Localytics Push Notification text limit

Tags: ios, push-notification, limit, message, localytics

I have integrated Localytics in one of the app(iOS) and its working fine, but as per the client requirement i need to increase the text limit(message sent in push notification), is there any option to change the text limit? if so please let me know

Here is [Localytics](http://support.localytics.com/IOS#Push_Notifications) which i am follwing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The character limit you see when creating the Push Campaign Localytics is based on Apple's payload limit. On Apple's "Local and Push Notification Programming Guide", they state the following:

> Each push notification includes a payload. The payload contains information about how the system should alert the user as well as any custom data you provide. The maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 256 bytes; Apple Push Notification Service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit.

For more information on Push Notification with Apple, you can find it at [`Apple documentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to reach out to us at support@localytics.com!

-Mike

Localytics

Comment: As of iOs 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)